# Problema com chamada de imagem Allegro por terminal C Mac

Tags: c, imagem, osx, terminal, allegro

Galera to com um problema aqui, estou fazendo um jogo usando o *Allegro*, estou compilando pelo terminal e ta tudo bem, só existe um porém, quando eu carrego uma imagem da falha ao carregar a imagem, o problema não é o código, eu já tentei rodar código que rodou em outros computadores, mas no meu não roda. O mais interessante é que se eu rodo o código pelo terminal usando ./executavel.exe ele roda normalmente como deveria, a imagem aparece e tudo tranquilo. Alguém sabe como eu posso resolver isso?
Deixando a duvida mais explicita: O executável só roda quando a execução é feita pelo terminal, quando eu dou 2 cliques no executável da erro ao carregar a imagem. Não sei dizer o por que do erro uma vez que quando eu não carrego a imagem, clicando 2 vezes no executável, ele roda normalmente, o que me faz pensar que a imagem é o problema. A questão é, como resolver sabendo que não é uma questão de código errado já que ele compila normalmente direto do terminal?

Eis o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//puxa a biblioteca allegro
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>

//fixo de tamanho de tela
#define LAR 1280
#define ALT 720

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//inicialização da janela
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *janela = NULL;

ALLEGRO_BITMAP *imagem = NULL;

//inicia allegro, caso erro da a msg
if(!al_init()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
    return -1;
}

al_get_standard_path(ALLEGRO_RESOURCES_PATH);

//cria a janela
janela = al_create_display(LAR, ALT);
if(!janela) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
    return -1;
}

//inicia primitivos
//al_init_primitives_addon();

//inicia a extenção de imagens
if(!al_init_image_addon()){
    fprintf(stderr, "Falha ao carregar image addon");
}

//carrega imagem
imagem = al_load_bitmap("imagem.jpg");
if (!imagem){
    fprintf(stderr, "Falha ao carregar imagem!\n");
    return -1;
}

//preenche a tela com alguma cor
al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

//desenha imagem
al_draw_bitmap(imagem, LAR/2 - (al_get_bitmap_width(imagem)/2),
               ALT/2 - (al_get_bitmap_height(imagem)/2), 0);

//atualiza a tela
al_flip_display();

//pausa a execução
al_rest(10.0);

//destroi imagem
al_destroy_bitmap(imagem);

//destroi variavel janela
al_destroy_display(janela);

return 0;
}
```

Meu Mac é Yosemite 10.10.5

F.A.Q

Sim a imagem tem o mesmo nome da qual eu me referencio no codigo

Sim ela esta na mesma pasta do executavel

Sim quando eu compilo eu chamo o -lallegro_image

Me falaram que poderia ser problema de permissão, porem eu n sei resolver isso, sou noob em OSX

Comment: Qual é o seu compilador e versão do allegro. Se não souber mande o tutorial que usou para instalar

Comment: @krystalgamer, meu compilador é o gcc e o Allegro é o 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Primeiro**

Tem a certeza que o `allegro` está instalado?

Mesmo que tenha vá ao diretório do seu `toolchain` ou do `IDE`(*deve ser o Xcode*) e verfique se dentro da pasta `include` tem lá uma pasta chamada `allegro5`. Se sim pode prosseguir

**Solução**

Vá aos `LIB_DIR` a que o seu linker vá procurar e veja se encontra algo começado por `liballegro*`, se encontrar é só chamar `-lallegro*` (*NOTA:    O asterisco é para ser substituido*).

Por exemplo na minha versão do allegro não necessito de indicar cada biblioteca que utilizo(imagem,som,fonte..) está tudo numa chamada `liballegro_monolith.dll.a`(*Windows*), e por isso é só compilar com `-lallegro_monolith`. Pode tentar e ver se funciona também.

**Como sei a que diretórios o meu compilador/linker acessa?**

É só escrever isto no terminal
`ld --verbose | grep SEARCH`

Irá listar todos os dirétorios possíveis.